# Problem with django templates

Tags: django, templates

Is there any solution to do something like this:

```
{% for c in categories %}
   {% for s in c.subcategory_set %}
   <li>{{ s.name }}</li>
   {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

???

Answer (score 3):

Reverse relations on a FK have a manager. As such, you need to use the `all()` method if you want to access all related objects.

```
{% for s in c.subcategory_set.all %}
```

Comment: This is it. Thank for that Ypu never sleep and always watch to give good answers :)